# how to change the background colour of CImage object in mfc?

Tags: mfc, dialog

I have an windows app which contains some dialogs. the dialogs have been built using mfc. I am drawing some images (.png) on every dialog using CImage::Draw() method. I want to mention that I am not using any picture contol on the dialog to render these images instead I am loading them at runtime using some handle.till this everything is ok. now when the image is loaded the background of those images are coming as white. the images in the resource file does not have the white background. my question is how to change the background of these images while drawing them on the dialog? I want the background of the image similar to the color of default dialog which i am using.
One more question the .png images are not rendering well(the images are scattered) in the dialogs of windows server 2008 R2 machine. what could be the possible remedy for this?
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your PNG images are obviously not 32-bit. You need an alpha channel and a transparent background. Open your images in e.g. Paint.NET. I bet your background is white there too! Regarding the image quality, are you stretching your images on draw?

Edit: For 8-bit imagers, I believe a call to [SetTransparentColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7bz08yk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is required. For 32-bit images, perhaps this function will do: [TransparentBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6h3tedyw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: the png images are 32-bit only. also the images are background. and I am sure the images are transparent. because in other programs the same images are doing gud. where I exactly m doing mistake. isn't there any other way to change the background of image while loading it?